# self-hosting SignalR on remote Mono server

Tags: ubuntu, mono, signalr, remote-server, self-hosting

I followed the following tutorial on how to achieve self-hosting of SignalR on a remote Mono server:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

With the help of the following webpage, I was able to get the remote server to start listening for remote clients (but only start, not actually handle requests properly):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ff53c95-11e1-4f65-88fd-72deea0eba74/wcf-service-library-vs-2010-not-working?forum=wcf
That page says to add "<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />" in App.Config, under "<runtime>".

The server can start listening (it outputs "Server running on http://*:8085"), but the moment it receives a request for "/signalr/hubs", it outputs the following error message:

Invalid type Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket for instance field Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationHandler+d_*0:5*_1
Invalid type Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket for instance field Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.OwinRequestExtensions+Hook+d_*0:5*_1

The client then receives the following error message: "GET http://ServerHere.com:8085/signalr/hubs 500 (Internal Server Error)".

After that, all I can do with the server is to press "enter" for it to terminate.

I'm using Mono Runtime 3.2.5 and Ubuntu 11.10.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the instructions had a mistake.

Instead of writing `WebApp.Start(url)`, write `WebApp.Start<Startup>(url)`.

This will cause the `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method in the `Startup` class to be called.

The server's error messages still show up, but they don't hinder anything.